# How do I display add model in tabular format in the Django admin?

Tags: python, django

I'm just starting out with Django writing my first app - a chore chart manager for my family. In the tutorial it shows you how to [add related objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#customize-the-admin-form) in a tabular form. I don't care about the related objects, I just want to add the regular object in a tabular form. This is what I have in my admin.py

```
from chores.models import Chore
from django.contrib import admin

class ChoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [ 
        (None,              {'fields': ['description', 'frequency', 'person']})
    ]   

admin.site.register(Chore, ChoreAdmin)
```

and I want when I click "add chore" that rather than seeing:

```
Description: _____
Frequency: ______
Person: _____
```

I want it to show:

```
Description: __________ | Frequency: _______ | Person: _____
```

Is this trivial to do, or would it take a lot of custom effort? And if it is easy, how do I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP is probably all set, but for new users reading this, refer to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/

Basically following part in above link:

---

The `field_options` dictionary can have the following keys:

`fields`: A tuple of field names to display in this fieldset. This key is required.

Example:

```
{
'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'city', 'state'),
}
```

---

Just like with the `fields` option, to display multiple fields on the same line, wrap those fields in their own tuple. In this example, the `first_name` and `last_name` fields will display on the same line:

```
{
'fields': (('first_name', 'last_name'), 'address', 'city', 'state'),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something to try,

```
class ChoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 list_display = ('description', 'frequency', 'person')
 list_editable = ('description', 'frequency', 'person')
```

Which should enable you to edit all your entries in a tabular form (if I've read the docs correctly)...

Comment: That enables editing, which *is* nice, so +1 for that, but I want the creation/add page to show up that way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's not a default ModelAdmin option for this, but you could change the CSS of the admin site or modify the layout of `change_form.html` on a per-model basis.

You could modify the admin site to use your custom CSS (on a per-model basis by subclassing the `ModelAdmin` with a `Media` class) and modify it (probably making use of the `body.change-form` CSS class) and make sure that the fieldsets are next to each other.

You could also create a template inside your templates directory with the name `/admin/chores/chore/change_form.html`. Unfortunately, the part that creates the actual form elements is not in a seperate block, so you should override the '`content`' block with your custom contents, copying a whole lot of the `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html` file.

Please refer to [relevent documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) for more information on this.