# How to render some of the fields of a Django form in the same row

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a Django form with two standard fields as:

```
empty_layer_name = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, label="Name of new Layer")

GEOM_TYPE = (
    ('MULTIPOINT', 'Points'),
    ('MULTILINESTRING', 'Lines'),
    ('MULTIPOLYGON', 'Polygons')
)

geom_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GEOM_TYPE, required=True, label="Type of Data")
```

Also I am building a Django form inside my def__init__ function as following:

```
...
for index in range(int(extra_fields)):
      self.fields['extra_field_{index}'.format(index=index)] = forms.CharField(min_length=3, max_length=15)
      self.fields['field_type_{index}'.format(index=index)] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FIELD_TYPE)
```

What I want is to print the generated fields values into the same row.

I guess this is something I need to do in my Template, when iterating through the form fields:

```
{% for field in form_empty_layer.visible_fields %}
       {{ field | as_bootstrap }}
 {% endfor %}
```

The question is how to get both generated fields in the same row?

Comment: You're using that tuple like a dictionary. Not done so. Do you want a dictionary of tuples or dictionary of dictionaries?

Comment: What do you mean, group them? Why would you want a tuple here? Django is expecting `self.fields` to be a dict mapping names to fields, a tuple wouldn't work at all.

Comment: I need to display fields in the same row. I read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575030/how-do-i-display-add-model-in-tabular-format-in-the-django-admin  that to accomplish that I need to place them in tuple. Right?

Comment: No. That is for the `fields` parameter in the Meta class of a ModelAdmin; it has nothing at all to do with the `fields` attribute on a ModelForm instance.

Comment: Ahh. I see. I guess my question needs editing. What I want is to be able to print SOME of form fields on the same line.

Comment: But that is up to your template, surely? Just output them in the same div.

Comment: Well not exactly. I have edited my question. When I iterate the form fields in my template, how can I put the current's iteration field together with the next iteration's?